# Checking whether "Today" matches interval + Start Date

Tags: c#, .net

I have 3 inputs:

- Current day - **DateTime.Today**
- Start Date - let say **03.03.2021** (wednesday)
- Interval - let say **7** days

I wanted to check whether **DateTime.Today** matches my interval, which is:

- 03.03.2021

next is:

- 10.03.2021

next is:

- 17.03.2021 (today!)

next will be:

- 24.03.2021

etc.

Only in that case - when **(StartDay + (Interval * X)) = Today**.

Anything better than TimeSpan Subtract?

```
    var today = DateTime.Today;
    
    var startDay = DateTime.Parse("2021-03-03");
    
    var sendDaysInterval = 7; // each every 7 days
    
    TimeSpan span = today.Subtract(startDay);
    
    if (span.Days % sendDaysInterval == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OK");
    }
```

Comment: Sonds simple, provided you know what to do with the time portion.

Comment: today.AddDays(-7);

Comment: "Better" how? Seems like you're looking for opinions, which is not something Stack Overflow does well. SO is more of a "just the facts" kind of place.

Comment: if (today.DayOfWeek == startDay.DayOfWeek) ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like,

```
StartDate =  StartDate.AddDays(Interval);

if(CurrentDate  == StartDate)

  return true;

else 

  return false;
```

Comment: But it won't be static interval, but in this case "weekly" interval - like +7, then +14, then +21 days etc.

Comment: Hint: Whenever you have `if (condition) return true else return false` it's more succinct to just do `return condition`